# Looping through an array to populate another array. (Or objects?)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Somewhat javascript newbie here. I'm trying to build up a query to get some data back from my province's Covid data repository. Without getting too much into why, I want to get all of the values from an array that looks like this:

```
fieldlist = {
    Vaccinedata: ['total_doses_administered', 'total_individuals_fully_vaccinated'],
    Casedata: ['Total_Cases', 'Number_of_patients_hospitalized_with COVID-19']
    }
```

To populate an object that looks like this:

```
coviddataset = {
  total_doses_administered: []
  total_individuals_fully_vaccinated: []
  Total_Cases: []
  Number_of_patients_hospitalized_with_COVID-19: []
}
```

So for I've got a loop that looks like this:

```
for (i in fieldlist)
    for (x=0; x<fieldlist[i].length;x++)
        console.log(fieldlist[i][x])
        field = fieldlist[i][x]
        coviddataset[field] = []
```

If I run the loop above, I can see that it is logging each value in each array key. Yay! But for some reason, the output I get for coviddata set using the following:

```
console.log('\nCoviddataset value is',coviddataset)
```

is:

```
Coviddataset value is { undefined: [] }
```

Any ideas why I can't seem to push these values as key pairs into my array?

Comment: In JS, code indentation does not matter. If you want to execute multiple statements inside a loop, or an `if` statement, you'll need to add curly braces: [How to use `for` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration). Without them, the code you have here only does `console.log()` in the loop, and only when it's done, the last 2 lines are executed.

Comment: Oh my god, a thousand face palms on my side. The weird thing is, I had been using curly braces inside each loop, then saw an example without them and though, oh, you just need to indent. So I guess if you are not nesting a loop, you don't need them? Man, javascript is weird.

Comment: The only time curly braces are not needed is when you only want to execute a single statement. I like to always use them, that way I'm always sure of what's being executed in the loop

Comment: I’m trying to figure out if Python has ruined me or JavaScript is just the worst.

Comment: can you show example what how exactly you want to transform that object